# Pauli-Villars Regularization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, regularization

I'm considering a real scalar field theory with Lagrangian density $$-L=\frac{1}{2}(\partial\phi)^{2}+\frac{1}{2}m_{0}^{2}\phi^{2}+\frac{\lambda_{0}\phi^{4}}{4!}$$

Let $m$ be the physical mass. I am regulating the divergent diagrams by implementing an explicit UV cutoff $\Lambda$.
  I'm trying to compute to one loop order how $m_{0}^{2}$ must vary as a function of the UV cutoff in order to keep the physical mass fixed.
I began by calculating the one loop contributions to the sum of all one-particle irreducible insertions into the propagator, which I will denote by $\pi(p^2)$.
There is only a single diagram that contributes, along with the counter term, which gives $$i\pi(p^2)=\frac{-i \lambda_{0}}{2}\int{\frac{d^4 k}{(2\pi)^{4}}\frac{i}{k^{2}+m_{0}^{2}-i\epsilon}\bigg(\frac{\Lambda^{2}}{\Lambda^{2}+k^{2}-i\epsilon}\bigg)^{2}}-i(Ap^2+Bm^2)$$
We want to choose $A$ and $B$ such that we have $\pi(-m^2)=0$ and $\pi'(-m^2)=0$.
I computed the integral, and I got the result that $$i\pi(p^2)=\frac{-i \lambda_{0}\Lambda^4}{32 \pi^2 (m_{0}^2-\Lambda^2)^2}\Big(2\Lambda^2log(\Lambda^2)-m_{0}^2log(m_{0}^2)+(m_{0}^2-2\Lambda^2)log(2\Lambda^2-m_{0}^2)\Big)-i(Ap^2+Bm^2)$$Then enforcing the conditions on $\pi(p^2)$ gives me that I need $A=0$ and $$B=\frac{- \lambda_{0}\Lambda^4}{32 \pi^2 m^2 (m_{0}^2-\Lambda^2)^2}\Big(2\Lambda^2log(\Lambda^2)-m_{0}^2log(m_{0}^2)+(m_{0}^2-2\Lambda^2)log(2\Lambda^2-m_{0}^2)\Big)$$

Now my question.  How do I use this result to determine how $m_{0}^2$ must vary with the UV cutoff in order to keep the physical mass $m$ fixed? Also, my formula for B includes both the physical mass $m$ and the other mass $m_0$.  Is that supposed to be the case?